# How to get propertyinfo of array nested property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, reflection

How can i get the propertyinfo of array child property. How can i access OtherAddress property in `customer[0]`

```
List<Orders> order = new List<Orders>(); 

Customer[] cs = { new Customer { CustNum = 5, OtherAddress = "Hello" }, new Customer { CustNum = 986, OtherAddress = "Other" } };

Customer[] cso = { new Customer { OtherAddress = "T", CustNum = 5 }, new Customer { CustNum = 777, OtherAddress = "other" } };

order.Add(new Orders(code + 1, "ALFKI", i + 0, 2.3 * i, "Mumbari", "Berlin", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 2, "ANATR", i + 2, 3.3 * i, "Sydney", "Madrid", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 3, "ANTON", i + 1, 4.3 * i, "NY", "Cholchester", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 4, "BLONP", i + 3, 5.3 * i, "LA", "Marseille", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 5, "BOLID", i + 4, 6.3 * i, "Cochin", "Tsawassen", cs));
```

To access the table operation

```
complexData = "customer.0.OtherAddress".split('.'); 
type = typeof(orders);

PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(complexData[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < complexData.Count(); i++)
{
    propInfo = propInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty(complexData[i]);
}
return propInfo.PropertyType;
```

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand the question. Could you please explain it more clearly and what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I want to access the otherAddress property. It is under array property. How can i get the propertyinfo of array child property

Comment: Do you want to get a PropertyInfo, or do you want to get the value of OtherAddress?

Comment: @Nikolaus I want propertyInfo of array  child property

Comment: In the bottom line, you want to extract a value from an arbitrary object, specified by the string path like "customer.0.OtherAddress". This includes retrieving property by name (like 'OtherAddress'), and retrieving array item by index (like '0'). Do I get it right?

Comment: @felix-b Yes , Index not a problem i need propertyinfo.propertytype of otheraddress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have classes like follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustNum { get; set; }
    public string OtherAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{
    public Orders(/* ..other parameters.. */ Customer[] customers)
    {
        this.CustomersArray = customers;
    }

    // I use name CustomersArray instead of Customer to make the answer
    // easier to read
    public Customer[] CustomersArray { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get the `Type` of the `Customer.OtherAddress` property as follows:

```
var propInfo = typeof(Orders)
   .GetProperty("CustomersArray")  // Orders -> Orders.CustomersArray
   .PropertyType.GetElementType()  // Customer[] -> Customer
   .GetProperty("OtherAddress");   // Customer -> Customer.OtherAddress
```

The main point is how to get the `Type` of `Customer` form the property `Orders.CustomersArray`. Since the `Type` of `Orders.CustomersArray` is array, you have to use `GetElementType()` to get the `Type` of array item, then proceed further down the path.

The generalized code that can retrieve `Type` of `Customer.OtherAddress` given a string path looks like this:

```
var complexData = "CustomersArray.0.OtherAddress".Split('.');
var type = typeof(Orders);
PropertyInfo propInfo = null;

for (var i = 0 ; i < complexData.Length ; i++)
{
    if (complexData[i] == "0")
    {
        type = type.GetElementType();
    }
    else
    {
        propInfo = type.GetProperty(complexData[i]);
        type = propInfo.PropertyType;
    }
}

return propInfo.PropertyType;
```

Also note that I replaced `.Count()` with `.Length` in the `for` loop, because `.Count()` comes from Linq and it's an O(n) operation -- it performs a loop over the `complexData` array every iteration of the `for` loop, which makes your `for` loop O(N^2). But this is just a side note.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way you can do this-

```
class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> ls = new List<Customer>();
ls.Add(new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "Name 1" });
ls.Add(new Customer() { ID = 2, Name = "Name 2" });

PropertyInfo info = ls[0].GetType().GetProperty("ID");
```

This is just an illustration. `GetProperty(<name>)` accepts property name in case sensitive format.

In your case you have to do something like this-

```
complexData = "Customer.0.OtherAddress".split('.'); 

PropertyInfo propInfo = cs[0].GetType().GetProperty(complexData[2]); //access cs through index
```

`complexData[2]` is the property name for `OtherAddress`. You can loop through the `complexData` to retrieve property info of other properties, but make sure you pass the property name correctly in case sensitive way.

Comment: how does your does retrieve the type of the OtherAddress property? Did you run it?

Comment: I think that the main point in the question was about passing through a property of an array type (from Orders.Customer of type Customer[]  to type Customer).